# Summation and other math symbols with helvet font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-operators, math-fonts, helvetica

I am trying to insert math operator symbols like summation, integration, etc... in a document setup with Helvetica font and lmodern, however, it does not compile them. I don't see any incompatibility issues and I do not know if I need additional packages apparently, all related to mathtype are included. I provide the mwe:

```
\documentclass[10.5pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=1.75cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{cuadro}[1] 
{colback=lavender!white,colframe=dukeblue!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1}
 \usepackage{colortbl}
 \usepackage{xcolor, soul}
 \usepackage{eurosym}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\EUR[1]{\mbox{#1\,\texteuro}}
 \usepackage{mathastext}
 \usepackage{newtxsf}
 \usepackage{
        lmodern,
        sansmath,
        babel,
        helvet,
        amsmath,
        eurosym
       }
       \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
        \everymath={\sf}
       \usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}
        \usepackage{multirow}
       \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{eurosym}
   \usepackage[margin=0.5cm, hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
   \definecolor{babyblueeyes}{rgb}{0.63, 0.79, 0.95}
 \definecolor{bluebell}{rgb}{0.64, 0.64, 0.82}
 \definecolor{lavenderblue}{rgb}{0.8, 0.8, 1.0}
 \definecolor{lightmauve}{rgb}{0.86, 0.82, 1.0}
 \definecolor{battleshipgrey}{rgb}{0.52, 0.52, 0.51}
 \definecolor{dukeblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.61}
 \definecolor{lavender}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.98}
\definecolor{arrowcolor}{RGB}{201,216,232}% color for the arrow filling
\definecolor{circlecolor}{RGB}{79,129,189}% color for the inner circles filling
 \colorlet{textcolor}{white}% color for the text inside the circles
 \colorlet{bordercolor}{white}% color for the outer border of circles
\usepackage{colortbl}
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.arrows,fit} % Timeline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% NEW PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{eso-pic}
%\geometry{left=2cm}%, textwidth=150mm}
%%%%%%%%%% COLORED BOXES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,line width =1pt,text width=5cm,minimum 
width=5cm,minimum height=1.5cm]{#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

 \newcommand{\myboxx}[1]{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,line width =1pt,text width=2cm,minimum 
   width=2cm,minimum height=1.5cm]{#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
 }

 \newcommand{\myboxxx}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,line width =1pt,text width=2cm,minimum 
  width=2cm,minimum height=0.5cm]{#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\cuadro}[1]{%
 \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
\setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr\wd0+13pt}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=dukeblue,boxrule=0.25pt,arc=4pt,
  left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt,boxsep=0pt,width=0.25pt]
#1
\end{tcolorbox}
 }
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{document}

 \textbf{\ul{Problem 1:}} We wanted to study the impact of rainy days on the number 
 of visits to the zoo. For this purpose, the following variables were observed for 
 the last ten months, where \textit{Y},  is the number of annual visits, in 
  thousands, and \textit{X}  is the number of rainy days per month. 

  \begin{center}
 \begin{array}{|c|cccccccccc|} \hline
  \text{Month} & 1 & 2& 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
\text{Rain days} & 5 & 9 & 14 & 18 & 16 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 19 & 23 \\ \hline 
\text{Visits} & 107 & 105 & 100 & 101 & 95 & 89 & 88 & 86 & 84 & 81 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{center}

In addition, the following auxiliary data are provided for the calculations:

 \boxed{$\sum x_{i}=167$} \hskip \boxed{$\sum y_{i}=936$} \hskip \boxed{$\sum 
 x_{i}^{2}=3097$} \hskip \boxed{$\sum y_{i}^{2}=88378$}\hskip \boxed{$\sum 
 x_{i}y_{j}=15197}$

CALCULATE:
 \begin{compactitem}
 \item[(a)] Calculate the linear correlation coefficient and interpret the result.
  \item[(b)] Obtain the least square regression line that explains the number of 
 monthly visits as a function of the number of rainy days as a function of the number 
  of rainy days.
  \item[(c)] What is the expected number of visits for the next month if the 
  Meteorological Institute reports 15 days of rainy days? How reliable is this 
   prediction?} 
 \end{compactitem}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Please make your MWE minimal, (2) the MWE contains a compilation error unrelated to your issue, `\EUR` is already defined. Thus please remove everything that is not related to your issue.

Comment: A lot of the font packages you load are not compatible with each other. Pick a set and don't load the others.

Comment: All compilation errors were solved and the font packages not compatible were removed. The code has been revised and now it works!!! Thanks!!!